# Splitting values in dataframe where keys matching

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes. In DF_1 there is about 800 repeating key values. In DF_2 100 unique key values and 20 columns with data values.

I want to create third dataframe where each matching value splitted by number of matches.

for example

Table 1

| id |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| A |
| C |
| A |
| A |
| C |

Table 2

| id | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 400 | 100 | 20 |
| B | 200 |  | 800 |
| C | 600 | 800 |  |

Output

| id | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | 25 | 5 |
| B | 200 |  | 800 |
| A | 100 | 25 | 5 |
| C | 300 | 400 |  |
| A | 100 | 25 | 5 |
| A | 100 | 25 | 5 |
| C | 300 | 400 |  |

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) after standardizing `df2` with the [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) of `df1['id']`:

```
out = (df1.reset_index()
          .merge(df2.set_index('id')
                    .div(df1['id'].value_counts(), axis=0),
                 on='id', how='left')
          .set_index('index').reindex(df1.index)
      )
```

Output:

```
  id   Col1   Col2   Col3
0  A  100.0   25.0    5.0
1  B  200.0    NaN  800.0
2  A  100.0   25.0    5.0
3  C  300.0  400.0    NaN
4  A  100.0   25.0    5.0
5  A  100.0   25.0    5.0
6  C  300.0  400.0    NaN
```